# TYPO3 extension b13/container use iteration in child rendering

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-extensions

I have a container that implements children like this:

```
<f:for each="{children_200}" as="child" iteration="iterator">
    {child.renderedContent -> f:format.raw()}
</f:for>
```

**how can I use iterator.index within the child ?** (i need a sequentially numbered id for a div, and need to handle this within the child for other javascript implementation)

if I use following I do have grip on `iterator` but lose `assets` within the child:

```
<f:for each="{children_200}" as="child" iteration="iterator">
    <f:render partial="ContainerIetem" arguments="{data: child}" />
</f:for>
```

I work with TYPO3 V11 but think the approach is the same starting from V9

Comment: Where do you need the div? Inside the child element? Around the child element?

Comment: @ThomasLöffler no, i need to ''transport'' the info into the partial ...

Comment: That's imho not possible. But the content element inside the container knows that it's inside the container. Maybe a DataProcessor for the content element could help?

Comment: @ThomasLöffler, that's beyond my tecnical capacity to 'originate', i can implement what you could suggest in an answer and take it from there ...

Comment: Here is a good approach by the extension owner: https://github.com/b13/container/issues/285#issuecomment-1223909983